# Number of balls inside a ball - metric space version

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a metric space $(X,d)$ and let $a>1$. Also, let $x\in X$ and $r>0$ small enough.

Is there an upper bound $N(a)> 0$ (independent of $x,r$) so that there can fit at most $N(a)$ **disjoint** balls of radius $r/a$ inside the ball $B(x,r)$?

I can see that this happens if $X=\mathbb R^n$... but I use volume of balls to check this. What can we say in the general case? What about more geometric $X$? I see that this is also true, for small balls, if $X$ is a manifold.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. E.g., consider the space $X$ comprising the coordinate axes in the space $\Bbb{R}^* = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb{R}^n$. $X$ looks like countably many copies of the real line identified at the origin metrized such that each pair of lines has the same metric as the union of the coordinate axes in $\Bbb{R}^2$. The open unit ball centred at the origin contains infinitely many pairwise disjoint open balls of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centred at the points at distance $\frac{1}{2}$ from the origin. Likewise the closed unit ball centred at the origin contains infinitely many pairwise disjoint closed balls of radius $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Hi, but they are not disjoint. They agree at 0.

Comment: I was thinking of open balls. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: Nice! What about $X$ finite dimensional?

Comment: @Curious You can take infinitely many lines intersecting at the origin in $R^2$, and make the distance between points on different lines large...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "$X$ finite dimensional". If you just take finitely many of the axes, then a proof along the lines of yours for $\Bbb{R}^n$ will show that there is a  finite upper bound, for given $r$. @TodorMarkov: sure you can visualise $X$ as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$, but the metric is not the induced metric,

Comment: @RobArthan, finite dimensional in the sense of Lebesgue covering dimension

Comment: @Curious: bringing in the Lebesgue covering dimension probably merits a new question.

Comment: @Curious Isn't the Lebesgue covering dimension in this case 1 anyway?

Comment: @TodorMarkov, hmm seems like it. good observation. every answer was really nice, but I will accept Rob's answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis $(e_n)$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Take $a=2$ and $ r=\epsilon $. Consider  the balls $B(\frac {\epsilon e_i} {3}, \frac {\epsilon } {3\sqrt 2})$. These balls are disjoint and they are all contained in $B(0,r)$. So $N(a)$ need not be finite.

Comment: Nice one! What about finite dimensional $X$?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy construction where you can have infinity:

Let $X$ be a metric space, and let $d(x, y)=1 \forall x \neq y \in X$. Of course, $d(x,x) = 0$. It's easy to check that $d$ is a metric.

Now, $B(x, 1) = X$. On the other hand, $B(x, a) = {x}$ if $a < 1$, so for any $a < 1$, $\cup_{y \in X} B(y,a) \subset B(x, 1)$ and the union is disjoint. So if $X$ is not finite, you can pack infinitely many balls.

Comment: That's a good one! What about more geometric $X$? but more general than a manifold?

Comment: @Curious I don't know what "geometric" means. In a metric space, the metric essentially defines your geometry, they're not separate things. If you have more structure, like a measurable space, then you can make arguments similar to those for volume (volume is a measure) - though I'm not sure if you need some conditions on the measure.

Answer (score 1):

In infinite-dimensional spaces, there’s a limit to the radii at which balls of unit radius can fit **infinitely many non-overlapping balls** of those radii; precisely, let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be Banach space with unit ball centered at the origin $B_X=B(0,1)$ and define the packing constant
$$P(X):=\sup\{r>0:B_X\text{ contains infinitely many non-overlapping } B(x,r)\}$$ then we have a formula given by $$P(X)=\frac{K(X)}{2+K(X)}\,$$ where $K(X)$ is the Kottman separation constant defined as $$K(X)=\sup\left\lbrace r:\|x_n-x_m\|\ge r\,,\forall n\ne m\,, \{x_n\}_n\subset B_X\right\rbrace\,.$$
For some spaces, the Kottman constant values are well-known; for instance, given the sequence space $\ell^p$ one obtains $$K(X)=2^{1/p}\,,~\,~\,~\,~\text{if $1\le p<\infty$}\,.$$ Thus, as example, the space $\ell^1$ of absolutely summable sequences can contain infinitely many non-overlapping balls of radius $r<\frac{1}{2}$ in its unit ball.

(For further reading, see for instance, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f857/7f978843efd0b7b96cd7cd7b94770907032a.pdf).

Comment: That's a really nice answer!